# Can I add an operation to a list in Python?

Tags: python

I am quite often using Python instead of pseudocode. For that, I would like to have a stack. I know that using lists is the way to go ([source](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks)), but I would like to use `myList.push` rather than `myList.append` to make clear that I use a stack.

I thought I could do something simple like

```
myList.push = myList.append
```

to define an alias for the append operation, but I get

```
    stack.push = stack.append
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'push'
```

Does a **short** solution for adding a push-operation to a list exist?

<sup>(It should not mess up my runnable Python-pseudocode)</sup>

Comment: btw - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566266/why-is-pythons-append-not-push

Comment: so your question is really can you assign an alias to `list.append(x)` where the alias would be something like `push(x)` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make a subclass of *list* like this:

```
class List(list):
    def push(self, x):
        self.append(x)
```

Use your custom class the same way you would use a regular list:

```
>>> s = List()
>>> s.push(10)
>>> s.push(20)
>>> s
[10, 20]
```

Comment: doesn't "push" add it to the front?  in which case .insert(0,x) should be used.

Comment: deques will be faster than lists for this purposes.

Comment: @monkut: that sounds reasonable, however, the inverse operation (`list.pop`) pops the last item off the list by default. So it's better to implement `push` with `list.append` so you don't have to `pop(0)` or override `pop` in the subclass.

Comment: good point, I wasn't thinking of pop.  Probably better to use append then.

Comment: For a LIFO stack, subclass from *list*, make *push()* delegate to *append()* for adding values, and use *pop()* for removing values.  For a FIFO queue, subclass from *collections.deque*, make *push()* delegate to *appendleft()*, and use *pop()* for removing values.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of redefining, how about aliasing the same function ?

```
class List(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.push = self.append
```

This would retain the functionality of append too.

Comment: This is OK. To preserve list construction semantics (e.g. `List((1,2,3,4))` you could make the `__init__` method accept `*args` and `**kwargs` and then pass these to the base class `__init__` via `super(List, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = []
>>> push  = a.append
>>> push(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I thought of but couldn't remember. Though, I accepted the other answer as I think adding 3 lines to my pseudocode is ok and the result looks a little bit cleaner => +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> stack = type('stack', (list,), {'push':list.append})()
>>> stack.push(1)
>>> stack.pop()
1
>>>
```