# What is the point of using the pop() on list?

Tags: python, list

I understand how it works but I don't see the purpose of it in an actual program. And if they did implement the pop() method why would they not implement a push() too?

Comment: I assume your talking about python? If so, I agree. There's the concept of left and right, and you need to know which one "append" appends to. A little convoluted, I think.

Answer (score 4):

What about `append()`? That's the equivalent to `push`.

The whole purpose is a quick way to use a list as a *stack* when convenient. It can also be used as a queue with the combination of methods `pop(0)` and `append()` . Although for this specific cases the best choice is `deque` from `collections.`

Comment: plus, pop() may have an index. You don't want to consume ram with a new list just for pop one element.

Answer (score 4):

They did implement push, but they split the functionality into `list.insert()` and `list.append()` instead.

`list.append()` is the equivalent of pushing a value onto the end. `list.insert()` is the inverse of `list.pop()` with an index; inserting the given value at the given index.

The `list.pop()` method is an alternative to `del listobject[index]` in that it returns the value at the index you are removing.

Note that Python lists are not limited to being used as a stack or queue, and `list.pop()` is a *later* addition to the `list` type to make removing-and-returning more efficient.

Comment: +1 I completely forgot `insert` :)

Comment: Wow, great. You answered all my questions. I understand it perfectly now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Pop is annoying to do otherwise:

```
popped = my_list[-1]
my_list = my_list[:-1]
```

Instead of just:

```
popped = my_list.pop()
```

The second part of your question is already answered by others - it's just called append instead.

Also see [Why is Python's "append" not "push"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566266/why-is-pythons-append-not-push)

Comment: or `del my_list[-1]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I have a feeling that's more efficient.

Comment: Yes, sort of. Certainly for deleting the last element. Deleting the *first* element is still efficient enough to make it worth your while, but internally the list *does* have to be rebuilt.

Comment: And nice find; this question could easily be seen as a dupe of that one.